# how to detect rectangles in an image using javacv or any other java library?

Tags: java, image-processing, crop, javacv

My requirement is to implement auto-crop in a scanned image so that unwanted parts in the image can be cropped off. The scanning material will be a rectangle shaped document. Is it possible to detect the rectangle shaped document from the scanned image and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following blog post, it might help:

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/